# Twilio Android, incoming call receives "onCancelledCallInvite: CallException code: 31008" when answered

Tags: java, android, twilio, voip

I have Twilio Voice implemented and working on Android. However, often upon answering a call we immediately receive **"onCancelledCallInvite: CallException code: 31008"**. The odd thing is that the connection stays active and voice communication with the caller continues to work. The issue is that the app thinks the call has dropped due to receiving the **onCancelledCallInvite**, and the call screen is closed. This creates an active orphaned call that is still in progress.

The app is using Voice Android version 5.6.2.

To answer the incoming call I call:

```
activeCallInvite.accept(context, callListener);
```

Below is the log file. Note in the log:

```
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): SipClient::disconnect
D/Twilio: [Core](517639025904): virtual void twilio::voice::SipCall::DisconnectCommand::executeCommand()
```

later followed by:

```
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): raiseCancelCallInvite
```

Also see in the log that after the CancelCallInvite the call continues.

Full Log:

I have Twilio Voice implemented and working on Android. However, often upon answering a call we immediately receive **"onCancelledCallInvite: CallException code: 31008"**. The odd thing is that the connection stays active and voice communication with the caller remains active. The issue is that the app thinks the call has dropped due to receiving the **onCancelledCallInvite**, and the call screen is closed. This creates an active orphaned call that is still in progress.

The app is using Voice Android version 5.6.2.

To answer the incoming call I call:

```
activeCallInvite.accept(context, callListener);
```

Below is the log file. Note in the log:

```
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): SipClient::disconnect
D/Twilio: [Core](517639025904): virtual void twilio::voice::SipCall::DisconnectCommand::executeCommand()
```

later followed by:

```
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): raiseCancelCallInvite
```

Also see in the log that after the CancelCallInvite the call continues.

Full Log:

```
D/TwilioVoicePlugin: Answering call
D/TwilioVoicePlugin: Answering call
D/Twilio: [Core](518822861256): API Call createAudioSource
    [Core](518822861256): API Call createAudioTrack
I/Twilio: [Core](518822861256): Adding audio track ...
D/Twilio: [Core](518822861256): API Call getName
    [Core](518822861256): API Call getTrackId
    [Core](518822861256): API Call isEnabled
D/Twilio: [Core](518822861256): API Call accept
D/Twilio: [Core](518822861256): accept
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): SipClient::disconnect
D/Twilio: [Core](517639025904): virtual void twilio::voice::SipCall::DisconnectCommand::executeCommand()
D/Twilio: [Core](518822861256): API Call getWebRtcTrack
D/Twilio: [Core](518822861256): API Call RTCIceServers
    [Core](518822861256): API Call RTCIceServer
I/Twilio: [Core](518822861256): Creating peer connection ...
I/Twilio: [Core](518822861256): Adding local stream to peer connection ...
D/Twilio: [Core](518822861256): Create initial local offer
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): onCreateSessionLocalDescription
D/CallInviteProxy: release
D/Twilio: [Core](518822861256): ~CallInviteImpl
    [Core](518822861256): ~CallerInfoImpl
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): OnSignalingChange
    [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): Signaling state: have-local-offer
D/ConnectivityReceiver: Network event received
    Ignoring network event, sticky broadcast
D/CallInviteProxy: onEvent
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): onSetSessionLocalDescription
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::networking 0x0x78a67ff800): void twilio::media::NetworkMonitor::onNetworksChanged()
    [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::networking 0x0x78a67ff800): Network Name: wlan0, Cost: 10, Type : Wifi, Preference : 127, Active : 1, id: 3, prefix : 192.168.2.x and key : wlan0%192.168.2.x/24
    [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::networking 0x0x78a67ff800): Network Name: lo, Cost: 0, Type : Loopback, Preference : 126, Active : 1, id: 2, prefix : ::1 and key : lo%::1/128
    [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::networking 0x0x78a67ff800): Network Name: lo, Cost: 0, Type : Loopback, Preference : 125, Active : 1, id: 1, prefix : 127.0.0.x and key : lo%127.0.0.x/8
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::networking 0x0x78a67ff800): New preferred network reported by manager: key: wlan0%192.168.2.x/24, type: Wifi, cost: 10, id: 3
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): Local SDP - v=0
    o=- 5771264047219087907 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.x
    s=-
    t=0 0
    a=group:BUNDLE audio
    a=msid-semantic: WMS 9fCAE34C40bC829B219de4fbd1BFea93
    m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:NyGP
    a=ice-pwd:9BOEneVWrZVH+BtFNTJIudM5
    a=ice-options:trickle
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 17:02:69:E9:B7:EE:72:47:0A:41:39:1F:3C:3F:FD:72:CE:04:28:28:91:0A:71:C9:FA:61:33:06:96:97:1D:4A
    a=setup:actpass
    a=mid:audio
    a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
    a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
    a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
    a=sendrecv
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
    a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
    a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
    a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
    a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
    a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
    a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
    a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
    a=rtpmap
    [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): twilio::voice::AsyncDnsResolver::AsyncDnsResolver(std::weak_ptr<DnsResolverObserver>)
    [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): AsyncDnsResolver resolving hostname = chunderm.gll.twilio.com
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): Gathered ICE candidate: candidate:926965826 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.2.x 38883 typ host generation 0 ufrag NyGP network-id 3 network-cost 10, id: SpXlrYSl
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): AsyncDnsResolver Resolved ip_addr = 54.85.119.44, error = 0
    [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): virtual void twilio::voice::SipClient::onResolveResult(twilio::voice::AsyncDnsResolver *, std::string, int)
    [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): onResolveResult for connect, hostname = sip:chunderm.gll.twilio.com:443;transport=tls, ip_addr = 54.85.119.44
    [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): New SipCall ..., this=0x78bc47dd00, handle = 4
I/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): Setting outbound proxy to: sip:54.85.119.44:443;transport=tls
D/CallInviteProxy: onEvent
D/EventPublisher: Start publishing events to : https://eventgw.twilio.com/v4/EndpointEvents
    {"name":"have-local-offer","group":"signaling-state","timestamp":"2021-03-03T02:49:46.289Z","level":"DEBUG","private":false,"payload_type":"application\/json","publisher":"twilio-voice-android","publisher_metadata":{"client_address":"FE80::EC6D:7AFF:FEE0:BB85","os_name":"android","os_version":"8.0.0","device_model":"SM-G935T","device_vendor":"samsung","device_type":"SM-G935T","cpu_architecture":"arm64-v8a","app_id":"com.MyApp.flutter","app_version":"0.1.0","app_build_number":"31","app_min_os_version":23,"app_target_os_version":30},"payload":{"timestamp_ms":1614739786285,"client_name":"5fc1a9b29d368c7292641c3e","call_sid":"CA335578454dc3db2d1f810944a6b51a97","message_sid":"RUc36021e53e6b591c645eb6d8f27fcd63","sdk_version":"5.6.2","platform":"android","direction":"INCOMING","selected_region":"gll"}}
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/EventPublisher: Start publishing events to : https://eventgw.twilio.com/v4/EndpointEvents
    {"name":"accepted-by-local","group":"connection","timestamp":"2021-03-03T02:49:46.307Z","level":"INFO","private":false,"payload_type":"application\/json","publisher":"twilio-voice-android","publisher_metadata":{"client_address":"FE80::EC6D:7AFF:FEE0:BB85","os_name":"android","os_version":"8.0.0","device_model":"SM-G935T","device_vendor":"samsung","device_type":"SM-G935T","cpu_architecture":"arm64-v8a","app_id":"com.MyApp.flutter","app_version":"0.1.0","app_build_number":"31","app_min_os_version":23,"app_target_os_version":30},"payload":{"timestamp_ms":1614739786301,"client_name":"5fc1a9b29d368c7292641c3e","call_sid":"CA335578454dc3db2d1f810944a6b51a97","message_sid":"RUc36021e53e6b591c645eb6d8f27fcd63","sdk_version":"5.6.2","platform":"android","direction":"INCOMING","selected_region":"gll"}}
D/CallInviteProxy: onEvent
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/CallInviteProxy: onEvent
D/EventPublisher: Start publishing events to : https://eventgw.twilio.com/v4/EndpointEvents
    {"name":"gathering","group":"ice-gathering-state","timestamp":"2021-03-03T02:49:46.325Z","level":"DEBUG","private":false,"payload_type":"application\/json","publisher":"twilio-voice-android","publisher_metadata":{"client_address":"FE80::EC6D:7AFF:FEE0:BB85","os_name":"android","os_version":"8.0.0","device_model":"SM-G935T","device_vendor":"samsung","device_type":"SM-G935T","cpu_architecture":"arm64-v8a","app_id":"com.MyApp.flutter","app_version":"0.1.0","app_build_number":"31","app_min_os_version":23,"app_target_os_version":30},"payload":{"timestamp_ms":1614739786319,"client_name":"5fc1a9b29d368c7292641c3e","call_sid":"CA335578454dc3db2d1f810944a6b51a97","message_sid":"RUc36021e53e6b591c645eb6d8f27fcd63","sdk_version":"5.6.2","platform":"android","direction":"INCOMING","selected_region":"gll"}}
D/Twilio: [Core](517639025904): mapToSipCall handle id is 1
D/Twilio: [Core](517639025904): casting handle id 1 to SipCall
    [Core](517639025904): onTerminated: reason 5, this=0x78bc47d300
    [Core](517639025904): onTerminated
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): raiseCancelCallInvite
D/Twilio: [Core](517639025904): ~SipCall(): 0x78bc47d300
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): Gathered ICE candidate: candidate:3243252118 1 udp 1686052607 66.25.218.226 38883 typ srflx raddr 192.168.2.x rport 38883 generation 0 ufrag NyGP network-id 3 network-cost 10, id: I2J/daT2
D/CallInviteProxy: onEvent
D/CallInviteProxy: onEvent
D/EventPublisher: Response: 200 - OK
D/EventPublisher: Start publishing events to : https://eventgw.twilio.com/v4/EndpointEvents
    {"name":"ice-candidate","group":"ice-candidate","timestamp":"2021-03-03T02:49:46.343Z","level":"DEBUG","private":false,"payload_type":"application\/json","publisher":"twilio-voice-android","publisher_metadata":{"client_address":"FE80::EC6D:7AFF:FEE0:BB85","os_name":"android","os_version":"8.0.0","device_model":"SM-G935T","device_vendor":"samsung","device_type":"SM-G935T","cpu_architecture":"arm64-v8a","app_id":"com.MyApp.flutter","app_version":"0.1.0","app_build_number":"31","app_min_os_version":23,"app_target_os_version":30},"payload":{"timestamp_ms":1614739786333,"client_name":"5fc1a9b29d368c7292641c3e","call_sid":"CA335578454dc3db2d1f810944a6b51a97","message_sid":"RUc36021e53e6b591c645eb6d8f27fcd63","sdk_version":"5.6.2","platform":"android","direction":"INCOMING","selected_region":"gll","transport_id":"audio","is_remote":false,"ip":"192.168.2.34","port":38883,"protocol":"udp","candidate_type":"local","priority":2122260223,"url":"","deleted":false,"network-cost":10,"network-id":3,"related_port":0,"level":"DEBUG","related_address":"","network-type":"Wifi","name":"ice-candidate","tcp_type":""}}
D/EventPublisher: Response: 200 - OK
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/EventPublisher: Start publishing events to : https://eventgw.twilio.com/v4/EndpointEvents
    {"name":"ice-candidate","group":"ice-candidate","timestamp":"2021-03-03T02:49:46.385Z","level":"DEBUG","private":false,"payload_type":"application\/json","publisher":"twilio-voice-android","publisher_metadata":{"client_address":"FE80::EC6D:7AFF:FEE0:BB85","os_name":"android","os_version":"8.0.0","device_model":"SM-G935T","device_vendor":"samsung","device_type":"SM-G935T","cpu_architecture":"arm64-v8a","app_id":"com.MyApp.flutter","app_version":"0.1.0","app_build_number":"31","app_min_os_version":23,"app_target_os_version":30},"payload":{"timestamp_ms":1614739786381,"client_name":"5fc1a9b29d368c7292641c3e","call_sid":"CA335578454dc3db2d1f810944a6b51a97","message_sid":"RUc36021e53e6b591c645eb6d8f27fcd63","sdk_version":"5.6.2","platform":"android","direction":"INCOMING","selected_region":"gll","transport_id":"audio","is_remote":false,"ip":"66.25.218.226","port":38883,"protocol":"udp","candidate_type":"stun","priority":1686052607,"url":"stun:34.203.251.117:3478","deleted":false,"network-cost":10,"network-id":3,"related_port":38883,"level":"DEBUG","related_address":"192.168.2.34","network-type":"Wifi","name":"ice-candidate","tcp_type":""}}
D/EventPublisher: Response: 200 - OK
D/EventPublisher: Start publishing events to : https://eventgw.twilio.com/v4/EndpointEvents
    {"name":"complete","group":"ice-gathering-state","timestamp":"2021-03-03T02:49:46.398Z","level":"DEBUG","private":false,"payload_type":"application\/json","publisher":"twilio-voice-android","publisher_metadata":{"client_address":"FE80::EC6D:7AFF:FEE0:BB85","os_name":"android","os_version":"8.0.0","device_model":"SM-G935T","device_vendor":"samsung","device_type":"SM-G935T","cpu_architecture":"arm64-v8a","app_id":"com.MyApp.flutter","app_version":"0.1.0","app_build_number":"31","app_min_os_version":23,"app_target_os_version":30},"payload":{"timestamp_ms":1614739786394,"client_name":"5fc1a9b29d368c7292641c3e","call_sid":"CA335578454dc3db2d1f810944a6b51a97","message_sid":"RUc36021e53e6b591c645eb6d8f27fcd63","sdk_version":"5.6.2","platform":"android","direction":"INCOMING","selected_region":"gll"}}
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
E/PowerManager: WakeLock finalized while still held: flutter.twilio.wakelock:TAG
D/EventPublisher: Response: 200 - OK
D/EventPublisher: Response: 200 - OK
D/EventPublisher: Response: 200 - OK
D/Twilio: [Core](517643171056): mapToSipCall handle id is 1
    [Core](517643171056): casting handle id 1 to SipCall
    [Core](517643171056): virtual void twilio::voice::SipCall::onFailure(resip::ClientInviteSessionHandle, const resip::SipMessage &)
D/Twilio: [Core](517643171056): Received incoming SIP message from infra:
     SIP/2.0 410 Gone
    Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 192.168.2.x;received=66.25.218.226;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---4ef18fe6d5ee728a;rport=53761
    Contact: <sip:172.25.4.x:10193>
    To: <sip:chunderm.gll.twilio.com:443;transport=tls>;tag=24354603_6772d868_b679c346-1ce5-43a2-9d27-1b1da25f6c36
    From: <sip:VoiceSDK@chunderm.gll.twilio.com>;tag=26504677
    Call-ID: xC-6diTaJuSYY76Id55WVw..
    CSeq: 1 INVITE
    Server: Twilio
    X-Twilio-CallSid: CA335578454dc3db2d1f810944a6b51a97
    X-Twilio-EdgeHost: ec2-54-85-119-44.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    X-Twilio-EdgeRegion: us1
    X-Twilio-Zone: US_EAST_VIRGINIA
    Content-Length: 0
    [Core](517643171056): onFailure
    [Core](517643171056): mapToSipCall handle id is 1
    [Core](517643171056): casting handle id 1 to SipCall
    [Core](517643171056): onTerminated: reason 0, this=0x78bc47ce00
D/Twilio: [Core](517643171056): Received incoming SIP message from infra:
     SIP/2.0 410 Gone
    Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 192.168.2.x;received=66.25.218.226;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---4ef18fe6d5ee728a;rport=53761
    Contact: <sip:172.25.4.x:10193>
    To: <sip:chunderm.gll.twilio.com:443;transport=tls>;tag=24354603_6772d868_b679c346-1ce5-43a2-9d27-1b1da25f6c36
    From: <sip:VoiceSDK@chunderm.gll.twilio.com>;tag=26504677
    Call-ID: xC-6diTaJuSYY76Id55WVw..
    CSeq: 1 INVITE
    Server: Twilio
    X-Twilio-CallSid: CA335578454dc3db2d1f810944a6b51a97
    X-Twilio-EdgeHost: ec2-54-85-119-44.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    X-Twilio-EdgeRegion: us1
    X-Twilio-Zone: US_EAST_VIRGINIA
    Content-Length: 0
    [Core](517643171056): onTerminated
D/Twilio: [Core](MediaFactoryImpl::signaling 0x0x78a67ff800): raiseCancelCallInvite
D/Twilio: [Core](517643171056): ~SipCall(): 0x78bc47ce00
D/CallInviteProxy: onEvent
D/Twilio: [Core](517639025904): mapToSipCall handle id is 4
    [Core](517639025904): casting handle id 4 to SipCall
D/Twilio: [Core](517639025904): onNewSession:
    SIP/2.0 200 OK
    Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 192.168.2.x;received=66.25.218.226;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---402e10cecf0821ea;rport=53779
    Record-Route: <sip:172.18.10.x:10193;r2=on;transport=udp;ftag=cfed5cb9;lr>
    Record-Route: <sip:54.85.119.44:443;r2=on;transport=tls;ftag=cfed5cb9;lr>
    Contact: <sip:172.25.4.x:10193>
    To: <sip:chunderm.gll.twilio.com:443;transport=tls>;tag=28038694_6772d868_ad31a15b-3d32-411e-a406-19783f7c8dc5
    From: <sip:VoiceSDK@chunderm.gll.twilio.com>;tag=cfed5cb9
    Call-ID: _L5_J-dQSDSd9JQ33RRtSw..
    CSeq: 1 INVITE
    Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE
    Content-Type: application/sdp
    Server: Twilio
    X-Twilio-CallSid: CA335578454dc3db2d1f810944a6b51a97
    X-Twilio-EdgeHost: ec2-54-85-119-44.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    X-Twilio-EdgeRegion: us1
    X-Twilio-Zone: US_EAST_VIRGINIA
    Content-Length: 1045
```

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'm not much of an Android developer I'm afraid, but maybe I have some ideas. A 31008 error implies the call may have been answered by another instance of the client identity. Is there a chance you are instantiating the voice SDK twice in the same app, so you both accept the call and receive the error?

Comment: @philnash I am also facing the same error in case of incoming call notification only. I am also making sure that there's only one device registered with a particular identity. Can you please help?

Comment: @tronku It would be better for you to post a new question so that you can share all the details of your issue without the baggage of this one. Let me know when you have asked the question and I will take a look.